# Instantiated classes vs static classes?

Tags: php

I'm struggling to know whether I should use a static or instantiated class.

I'm not sure I understand why you would use either apart from, a static class should be used to work on data where as a instantiated class has its own data.

I'm not sure how this apples to my work, for example, I have a model that gets data from a database (a list of products).

If my above assumption is correct then I should instantiate the model, as the class has it's own data.

And for example, if I then had a helper class that converted dates, this should be static, as it just returns data in a different format.

Is all of this correct, can anyone explain to me clearer or any sort of rules I should use when deciding between a static and instantiated class?

Comment: Read this: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/)

Comment: Really, there is no such thing as a static class, only a static _method_ within a class.

Comment: @deceze Nice write-up, worth the read.

Comment: @FDL: Though there's *technically* no such thing *in PHP*, they do exist in other languages (like C# and VB.  VB calls them "modules", but it's the same thing).  PHP can emulate them pretty closely with a `final` class that has only static members and a private constructor (that ideally throws a `BadMethodCallException` or the like).  But the main part is simply having nothing but static members.

Answer (score 2):

A *static class* isn't really a thing. You may be talking about a *class*, as distinguished from an *instance* of that class. A class can have properties and methods that are declared static using the `static` keyword. The `static` keyword applied to a property means you cannot access that property using an instance.

```
class Foo {
    public static $prop = 123;
}

php > echo Foo::$prop
123
php > $f = new Foo(); $f->prop;
PHP Strict standards:  Accessing static property Foo::$prop as non static in php shell code on line 1
```

However, you can access static methods either way:

```
class Bar {
    public static function meth() { echo "Hello, World\n"; }
}
php > Bar::meth()
Hello, World
php > $b = new Bar();
php > $b->meth();
Hello, World
```

In spirit, a static method is a good thing. It's a commitment that this method's output doesn't depend on the state of the object. But that's not to say it's guaranteed to be stateless, because there's another use for the `static` keyword: Static variables:

```
class Baz {
    public static function m() {
        static $callCount = 0;
        echo ++$callCount;
    }
}
php > Baz::m();
1
php > Baz::m();
2
php > $x = new Baz(); $y = new Baz();
php > $x->m();
3
php > $y->m();
4
…
```

So statics are a way you can store state in the class itself, independent of the instance. You can even use them for message-passing between instances of the same class. To be honest, the valid uses for that are few and far between, and it is hard to cover *stateful* statics directly with behavioral tests.

Another use for statics is carrying class-specific information. Let's say you want a whole bunch of classes to have a `log` method that always includes some class-specific information in the log message.

```
trait Xyzzy {
    public static function log($msg) {
        printf('[%s] %s', static::$_identifier, $msg);
    }
}
class Fuzzy {
    use Xyzzy;
    private static $_identifier = __CLASS__;
}
php > $f = new Fuzzy();
php > $f->log('hello, world');
[Fuzzy] hello, world
```

So if you feel a static is the right approach, because a method is

1. Contextually appropriate for the class and stateless, or
2. Carries state for the class.

Then you should use a static. It can make testing harder, but the tests are here to support you, not get in your way.

By the way, recent versions of PHPUnit [can test a subset of static methods](http://sebastian-bergmann.de/archives/883-Stubbing-and-Mocking-Static-Methods.html) using late static bindings.

Answer (score 1):

I've written about this extensively here: [How Not To Kill Your Testability Using Statics](http://kunststube.net/static/). To summarise it:

- static class methods are nothing more than regular functions
- if you do not instantiate your classes, you may as well not be using classes in the first place, since you're not working with *objects* and OOP without objects is just P, regular old procedural programming
- objects are there to decouple and abstract parts of your application; those parts include "data entities" as well as things like a database connector and business logic parts, *everything* can and should be an object
- static properties and methods are mostly *helpers* and used for some special cases, they are not the main focus in *object oriented programming* and should not be the overarching design philosophy

Choice quote from the linked article:

> Obligatory car analogy:
>
> Class Oriented Programming is like buying a car to let it sit in the
>   driveway, opening and closing its doors repeatedly, jumping around on
>   the seats, occasionally turning on the windshield wipers, **yet never
>   once turning the ignition key and taking it for a drive. It is missing
>   the point entirely.**

Comment: Static methods have one pretty significant advantage over free functions, though: you can autoload classes, but (as of yet) not functions.

Comment: And you can "namespace" some variables inside the class as well, yes. But those are extremely minor things and are no argument at all in the *static vs. instantiate* question.

Comment: They are, however, a counterpoint to the "you may as well not be using classes in the first place" argument.  Were function autoloading possible, i wouldn't recommend a static class at all; instances do tend to be better *if* OOP is the intent.  (Though variable classes + LSB + `private` go quite a way towards making a static class nearly an object in its own right.  It's roughly equivalent to a singleton minus the `getInstance` and magic properties.)